# Is ARM NEON thread-safe in multi-thread, multi-process or multi-core environment?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, multicore, neon, multiprocess

Does ARM NEON intrinsics itself have any technique to safely work in multi-thread, multi-core and multi-process environment or not? If yes, can you please cite the documents where this problem is mentioned because I cannot find one. If no, what to do to make sure that NEON ARM is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit like asking if basic math (addition, subtraction, etc.) is thread-safe… it can be used in an unsafe way, but there isn't anything inherently unsafe about NEON.

Comment: The ARM NEON Programmer guide specifies that multi-tasking is supported if the OS supports saving and restoring NEON and floating register file. May I ask if Ubuntu Linux supports that or not?

Comment: I would think that your are fine in user space, but not for kernel code.

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant issue that comes to mind is whether the platform you're using supports the hard float or soft float ABI.
According to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-using-the-hard-float-or-the-soft-float-version-of-debian
you can check whether you're on an `armhf` system. If you are, then using the NEON instructions is the same as using any other user-space instruction. The NEON instructions are present and the operating system knows how to save and restore the relevant registers on exceptions and interrupts without you having to worry about it.